# How to access parents data value in vuejs with the template syntax

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

In my VueJS app I am using bootstrap-vue and want to use iframe inside a collapsable elements `b-collapse`. Because of some problems with iframe content and resizing (problem not related here) I found out that if I enable/disable `b-embed` with conditional rendering it works.

The parent component `b-collapse` has a data element called `show` which change its state if toggle is clicked. In my `HelloWorld` component I want that `b-collapse` can pass it's `show` value into the `if` check of `b-embed`.

My approach with `this.$parent.$data.show` isn't working and I am not sure if there is any better way to do so.

```
<template>
<div>
  <b-btn v-b-toggle.logs>
    <span class="when-opened">Close</span>
    <span class="when-closed">Open</span>
    Trace
  </b-btn>
  <b-collapse id="logs">
    <b-embed :src="src" v-if="this.$parent.$data.show"></b-embed>
    <div>Data: {{this.$parent.$data.show}}</div>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { Prop, Component, Inject } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  src = "http://localhost:7681/";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Pass `show` as [a property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) to the child component.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

`parent.vue`

```
<template>
    <Child :show="myShow"></Child>
</template>
<script>
    import Child from './child'
    export default {
        data () {
              return {
                   myShow: 'StackOverflow'
              }
        },
        components: {Child}
    }
</script>
```

`child.vue`

```
<div>
  <b-btn v-b-toggle.logs>
    <span class="when-opened">Close</span>
    <span class="when-closed">Open</span>
    Trace
  </b-btn>
  <b-collapse id="logs">
    <b-embed :src="src" v-if="this.$parent.$data.show"></b-embed>
    <div>Data: {{this.$parent.$data.show}}</div>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
<script>
     export default {
          props: {
               show: {
                   type: Number,
                   require: true 
               }
          }
     }
</script>
```

Or use [`vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to do this.

Comment: actually what I want is that in my HelloWorld component b-collapse set his value of `show` in `b-embed` `v-if`. I can't modify b-collapse/b-embed as they are part of 3rd party bootstrap-vue.